# wordpress custom post type template file loop 404

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am working with a homemade theme, trying to keep it light weight, for a specific site. So far in development i am just using the index.php file to view pages and posts, both working smoothly and simple. I have a custom post type added, though, and when i try to open a single custom post, the index.php file loads, but nothing loads in the loop inside it. I guess that loops dont find any post at tall. My guess is something in the index.php or the register_post_type is going bananas. What do you think?

My index.php (slimmed):

```
<?php get_header();  ?>

  <div class="hero-unit">
  <?php get_template_part('hero');  ?>
  </div>

        <?php  
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        the_content(); //disconnected the content just to see if i get response, but nothing appears
        /*get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); */

    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>



<?php get_template_part('featured'); ?>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

My register_post_type in functions:

```
/* Custom Post Types */

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'kalender',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Kalender' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Kalenderpost' )
      ),
      'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'custom-fields',
            'thumbnail'
        ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

Any idea of what goes wrong? When i open a (WP-domain)/kalender/postname URL from the said single post in WP, it shows the full theme, except the content that should be found in the loop. If i try a trouble-shooting-loop with a 404 respons, it activates, like there are no matching post at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache server?

Make sure that rewrite module is enabled.

Also, check and see if .htaccess file has any issues or not.

Comment: Thank you! So far the project is just local on Mamp, so yeah it's Apache. I will try that and can also test by setup the installation on my test server, to see if it differs.